# Android-sdk folder doesn't appear inside Program files

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed Android tools and platforms but the Android doesn't appear inside Program files. And my Eclipse doesn't recognize Android.

Comment: ohhhoo... so you have forgot where you installed sdk while installation!

Answer (score 2):

> I have installed Android tools and platforms but the Android doesn't appear inside Program files.

It is not supposed to.

> And my Eclipse doesn't recognize Android.

Please install the ADT plugin for Eclipse: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html